# how can i load a file in ruby on rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

am trying to load a file where i have all my setting into rails console.
i want to do it because when i use the console there is too much repetition .
thank you

Comment: Please expand your answer to include an example of what you're currently doing in order to load the console.

Answer (score 9):

You can set configs of IRB using `.irbrc` file located in your home directory.

You can use `load`, `require` and whatever you want there.

Adding something like `require 'rubygems'` and `require 'pp'` will help. Some people customize the file more heavily. See [this](http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/12/my-irbrc-for-consoleirb/) for example.

Comment: Link is dead perhaps

Answer (score 6):

From within Rails console or IRB you can load a file with the [require](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005941) method. For example `require foo.rb` will execute all the statements in `foo.rb`.  You can use relative or absolute paths.

Comment: I had to put quotes around the filename, to avoid a `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'foo' `

Answer (score 0):

As stated before you can use .irbrc file, take a look here http://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles to see how to separate your rails specific code into a railsrc file.